# Can I make my density plot animation run faster?

Tags: plotting, animation, wolfram-cloud

I've been messing around on an online Wolfram Cloud note book. I evaluated the following line of code:

```
Animate[
  DensityPlot[Sin[x - t]Sin[y + t] + Sin[x + t]Sin[y - t], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}], 
  {t, 0, 5}, 
  AnimationRunning ->False]
```

However, when I try to run the animation it lags. In fact, it lags so bad it takes up to ten seconds for it to run. Is there a way to get it to run smoother?

Comment: Works fine on a Mac desktop.  No delays at all.  Or try:  `{t, 0, 5, .1}`.

Comment: I'm also running on a Mac desktop and I agree with what David said. Your problem may be more with your internet connection than with Mathematica.

Comment: Ohh.... on the *cloud*!  Why run such simple code in the cloud, where communication is the delay.  It is so much faster to run it locally.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Because in the cloud is free, and I'm cheap.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine on my desktop, so I'm guessing a bit here. But one thing you could do to speed it up a little at the expense of some initial overheads might be to create the list of plots in advance and then animate them with `ListAnimate`.

First, create the list of plots with `Table`:

```
plotlist = 
  Table[DensityPlot[
    Sin[x - t] Sin[y + t] + Sin[x + t] Sin[y - t], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3,
      3}], {t, 0, 5, 0.1}];
```

This will take a little time, but could improve the rendering time of the animation. Obviously you can decrease the step size if you want to make the transitions smoother. Then `ListAnimate` the list:

```
ListAnimate[plotlist]
```

On my machine, I noticed an improvement in the quality of the fames, but that's something you could play around with through the options in `DensityPlot`.

Comment: The question seems to be about wolfram cloud.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, I realise that. And I know nothing about wolfram cloud. I figured there was a chance that this approach would minimize the lag by trying to put as much of the computation as possible outside `Animate`. That may well be misguided, but I thought it worth a try.

Comment: It may, it even should, but I don't have time to try and one never knows ;) Let's wait for OP.